# hadoop install on round-robin DNS

Tags: installation, hadoop, cluster-computing

I want to install hadoop on a round-robin DNS environment. I have a bunch of machines sharing a common user environment and a common name. These machines are equal. The round-robin DNS runs on a branch of machines. Each machine has its own IP address and host name. It is our school's machines. But these machines share a common name. When I login, my terminal shows which machine I am on.

The problem is that I make change on one machine, the changes applies to all other machines.

I follow the instruction of michael-noll's multi-node hadoop. I need to configure master node.
But what I did to master node applies to slave nodes. That said, I cannot differentiate master and slave nodes.

So, can I install hadoop in such environment?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure why you would want to install Hadoop using a round-robin DNS, but no, you cannot do this with Hadoop.  Every single node needs to have a unique host name.

Comment: Yes. Every single node has unique host name. The round-robin DNS runs on a branch of machines. Each machine has its own IP address and host name. It is our school's machines. But these machines share a common name. When I login, my terminal shows which machine I am on.

Comment: The Namenode saves every block with its host machine. If you're round-robin' the DNS the Namenode will not find the blocks on the machine though.